# How to make an executable file from a c object file?

Tags: c, object-files

How to make an object file to executable file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122446/how-does-c-linking-work-in-practice

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to link the object file.  Your command:

```
gcc -c -o file.cgi file.c
```

compiles file.c into an object file (which would typically be called `file.o`).  If you get rid of the '`-c`', it will generate the executable directly:

```
gcc -o file.cgi file.c
```

Alternatively (more useful if you have multiple files and don't want to compile all files when only one has changed), do it in two steps:

```
# Compile only
gcc -c -o file.o file.c
gcc -c -o file2.o file2.c
# Link
gcc -o file.cgi file.o file2.o
```

Answer (score 4):

If your file is a `.o` file that contains a `main` function you just need to link it, for example `gcc file.o -o executable`

Answer (score 0):

Use the ld command. "ld file.o -o executable. This will give executable.

Comment: `ld qgb.o`
qgb.cpp:16: undefined reference to `system'